# Icon to begin transition in the centre of screen

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am attempting to make the icon appear in the middle of the screen before it transitions off to the left. Here is my code at the moment:

```css
#courseIcon {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
  margin-left: -125px;
}

/* ICON TRANSITION */
.moveIcon {
  -webkit-animation: moveIcon 2s;
  animation: moveIcon 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveIcon {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveIcon {
  from {
    transform: translateX(500px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="courseIcon" class="moveIcon"></div>
```

At the moment I have just set `translatex: 500px` as this is roughly half of the screen I am viewing it on. Is there a way of getting the transition to start in the centre of the page, regardless of the screensize? Here is my code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyfkm1hj/).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `50vw` would be half the viewport width. Might need to offset it back by `50%` to centre the icon itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Position `#courseIcon` absolutely
- Use transform/translate to begin in middle of the screen
- Animate using `transform/translate` for GPU-accelerated smoothness
- Remove `from` clause (unnecessary)
- To prevent the `animation` from resetting upon completion, use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

**Edit**: Removed `calc` from `animation` position calculation. As @TemaniAfif smartly points out, IE11 does not support transitioning values set with `calc()`.

```css
#courseIcon {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* ICON TRANSITION */
.moveIcon {
  -webkit-animation: moveIcon 2s;
  animation: moveIcon 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveIcon {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50vw, -50%);
  }
}

@keyframes moveIcon {
  to {
    transform: translate(-50vw, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="courseIcon" class="moveIcon"></div>
```

Comment: @Eddie pay attention if you will target IE borwser as calc is not supported inside transform (https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the use of left (or right) and you won't need any complex calculation:

```css
#courseIcon {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100) center/contain no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

/* ICON TRANSITION */
.moveIcon {
  animation: moveIcon 2s forwards 3s;
}

@keyframes moveIcon {
  to {
    left:0;
  }
}

body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="courseIcon" class="moveIcon"></div>
```

You can also do it like below without the use of `calc()` in case you need better browser support:

```css
#courseIcon {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://placehold.it/100x100) center/contain no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

/* ICON TRANSITION */
.moveIcon {
  animation: moveIcon 2s forwards 3s;
}

@keyframes moveIcon {
  to {
    left:0;
    transform:translate(0%,-50%);
  }
}

body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="courseIcon" class="moveIcon"></div>
```

Comment: You'll get much better/smoother animation with `transform` over `left`. You know better! :) Also, your example isn't vertically centered, as OP stated he wants.

Comment: @AndyHoffman you already provided the transform so I am providing an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for vertically centering.

Comment: Also, is `calc(-50vw - 100px)` really *more complex* than `calc(50% - 50px)`?

Comment: @AndyHoffman `calc(50% - 50px)` is used for the centring, it's not relevant to the animation. you know that we can centre using a lot of ways (flexobox, negative margin, translate, etc etc) ... the animation is the relavant part here

Comment: Yes, and your suggestion is to animate it poorly with `left`, which left me confused.

Comment: @AndyHoffman so we should not provide another solution because you provided the *best* one? there is no *poor* or *better* solution for me on SO. There is different answers providing alternative method. Someone else may also provide an animation with margin. You will think it's a bad idea but it's simply another alternative.

Comment: I see your point. Hopefully you can see mine, too. For the record, I'm a huge fan of yours.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I see your point and I already upvoted your answer. by the way I have edited to include another way (still with left) and without any use of calc. Not *better* but it can be helpful if browser doesn't support calc.

Comment: I am currently updating my example as well to remove `calc` since OP mentioned in the comments he wanted the box to stop at the edge of the screen (still visible).

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for letting me know about browser support, this will be used on a variety of browsers so that's great, thanks!

Comment: @Eddie I updated my answer so IE support is included :)